# PHP foreach, getting Win/Total Ratio

Tags: php, foreach

I got this code, and I am trying to get the Win/divided by total games played number, which should be under 1. Like 0.75.

```
foreach($dat as $stats) {
 if($stats['championId'] != 0) {
    echo '<br><br>Champion ID : '.$stats['championId'];
     echo '<br>Total Games Played : '. $stats['totalGamesPlayed']; 
    foreach($stats['stats'] as $stat) {
        if($stat['statType'] == 'TOTAL_SESSIONS_WON')
        echo '<br> Won: '.$stat['value'];
    $ratio = $stat['value'] / $stats['totalGamesPlayed'];
        echo '<br>' .$ratio;
    }        
  }
}
```

And that piece of code is right, expect the part of the $ratio.
Cause when I echo it, I get like 30 numbers, and only 1 is the right one.
Can you guide me through that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need curly brackets `{ ... }` around the second `if` statements. If you don't use curly brackets, only the first statement after the `if` condition will be evaluated as part of the [`if` construct](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

```
foreach($dat as $stats) {
  if($stats['championId'] != 0) {
    echo '<br><br>Champion ID : '.$stats['championId'];
    echo '<br>Total Games Played : '. $stats['totalGamesPlayed']; 
    foreach($stats['stats'] as $stat) {
      if($stat['statType'] == 'TOTAL_SESSIONS_WON') { // <-- here...
        echo '<br> Won: '.$stat['value'];
        $ratio = $stat['value'] / $stats['totalGamesPlayed'];
        echo '<br>' .$ratio;
      } // <-- ... and here
    }        
  }
}
```